# Не отрабатывает выезд блока при нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть `<button>` с классом `On_seorch_interface`, при нажатии на него выезжает `<div>`. А при нажатии на `<button>` с классом `getstyle` `<div>` уезжает.

Нормально это отрабатывает только раз. Далее скрипт "живёт своей жизнью". В чём ошибка?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout_id;
    var tgl = 1
    $(".getstyle").click(function() {
        if (tgl !== 1) {
            timeout_id = window.setTimeout(function() {
                $(".serch_fild_block").animate({
                    height: 'hide'
                }, 800, 'easeInCirc')
            }, 100);
            $(".form-controls").animate({
                marginLeft: '2500px'
            }, 900, 'easeInCirc')
        }
    });

    $(".On_seorch_interface").click(function() {
        if (tgl === 1) {

            $(".serch_fild_block").animate({
                height: 'show'
            }, 800, 'easeInCirc');
            timeout_id = window.setTimeout(function() {
                $(".form-controls").animate({
                    marginLeft: '500px'
                }, 1000, 'easeOutQuart')
            }, 800);
            tgl = 0
        } else {
            tgl = 1
        }
    });
});
```

Вот весь код :http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/115/

Comment: @Regent  добавил в песочницу

Comment: @Regent, убрал лишний код

Comment: Что-то в fiddle (даже с подключением jQuery UI) всё очень плохо с местоположением `.getstyle`. Да и в целом вёрстка странно выглядит. Возможно, на сайте это и нормально выглядит. Лично у меня после нажатия на "Enter" блок никуда с экрана не делся - из одного дальнего угла он уехал в другой.

Comment: @Regent, на сайте он исчезает .

Comment: `marginLeft: '2500px'` даёт плохой результат в fiddle. На досуге исправьте ошибки у себя в коде в словах: вместо `heigth` должно быть `height` (стили `body, html`), вместо `seorch`, равно как и вместо`serch`, - `search`, `fild` -> `field`.

Comment: @Regent, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я правильно понял, что Вас смущает, что после нажатия на `button` с классом `getstyle`, Вам необходимо уже два раза нажать на `button` с классом `On_seorch_interface`, чтобы появился блок с виртуальной клавиатурой? Если да, то вставьте `tgl = 1` после

```js
$(".form-controls").animate({
    marginLeft: '2500px'
}, 900, 'easeInCirc');
```

, а блок `else` в обработчике клика кнопки с классом `On_seorch_interface` удалите.